# COMPLUS_ForceENC and ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT automatic added in web.config in EF Core 3

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.0

After updating EF Core to version 3. My solution started to add below in `web.config` automatically. This causes problems during deploy because these parameters should be overridden in each environment. How should I do get this blank?

```
<environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
</environmentVariables>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem worthy of a full answer as I still don't know why it happens, but I found upgrading to Visual Studio 16.8.3 fixed this for me

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/net-enc-support-for-lambdas-and-other-improvements-in-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way was to add

```
 "ancmHostingModel": "OutOfProcess",
```

in the `launchSettings.json`

So the JSON for iisexpress looks like

```
 "IIS Express": {
      "ancmHostingModel": "OutOfProcess",
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
      }
    }
```

And now the `web.config` can be nice and clean